# Why does excel macro crash with "excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action" but doesn't utilize any other application/file?

Tags: excel, vba, ole

I've seen a lot of posts about this OLE action error, but the difference here is that the macro that I am running isn't importing/exporting any data and isn't triggering actions in any other program (at least not intentionally), which is what I've come to learn is generally the cause. Here is the VBA that generates the error:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim varResponse As Variant

    varResponse = MsgBox("This will permanently delete selected rows. Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo, "WARNING")
    If varResponse <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

    Set Rs = Selection

    For i = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
        If Range(Rs.Address).EntireRow.Cells(i, 12) <> "d" Then
            MsgBox "Selection contains cells that can not be removed. Revise selection.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Selection"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next

    For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Worksheet.Unprotect
    Next

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("backup_estimate").Cells.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("backup_actual").Cells.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("backup_invoice").Cells.Clear

    sourceOld = Selection(1).Row
    sourceSize = Selection.Rows.Count

    Worksheets("Estimate").Range(Rs.Address).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("backup_estimate").Range("A1")
    Worksheets("Actual Cost").Range(Rs.Address).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("backup_actual").Range("A1")
    Worksheets("Invoice Tracking").Range(Rs.Address).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("backup_invoice").Range("A1")

    Sheets(Array("Estimate", "Actual Cost", "Invoice Tracking")).Select
    Range(Rs.Address).EntireRow.Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=x1Up
    ActiveSheet.Select

    For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Worksheet.Protect
    Next
End Sub
```

The purpose of the macro is to delete the same selection of data and rows across 3 of the 6 sheets in this specific workbook, and shift all remaining data up.

When triggering the macro, it will more often than not freeze the instance of excel and give me that error about 10-20 seconds later (it doesn't happen every time). For reference, the "backup_estimate" and other backup sheets are strictly temporary data storage for use by another "undo last action" macro that I have set up.

I do have a single plug-in that I use periodically (blue-beam), but I've encountered this error with the plugins all disabled AND the "ignore other applications that use DDE" option checked (one of the fixes suggested on another post).

Comment: `x1Up` should be `xlUp`  You should always use `Option Explicit` for exactly this reason.   If you disable the add-in and all other code, including any event-handling routines, does it still error?

Comment: @TimWilliams The only other code that I have in this workbook are 2 other manually triggered macros (one to add blank rows, one to undo row deletes), and variable declarations. With those (excepting the variables) deleted, the problem still persists.

Comment: Sorry - I don't have any useful guesses.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm starting to think it might just be an issue with my computer OR my install of excel. I just got the same freeze and error without running anything, simply hitting 'enter' on a cell with a simple numerical expression evaluation. *sigh* Will continue investigating.

Comment: Try quitting Excel, then restart and see if that helps. If not, try re-booting Windows.

Comment: Sounds like an add-in issue (at least, every time something like that has happened to me, that's what the problem turned out to be...)

Comment: 1.  Disable all other Add-ins, 2. Go into Task Manager and make sure that there no other instances of Excel running in the background.

Comment: Probably not related, but having an undeclared variable named `Worksheet` in an Excel project seems like it's asking for trouble.

Comment: @Comintern Yeah, I followed Tim's advice and added Option Explicit to all my macros and declared variables for the sheets instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps explain the issue at all, but a "fix" so far has been to alt-tab to another window and then back any time excel seems to lock up. For the last two days that has avoided the error prompt with 100% success. Still no idea what is causing it to begin with though. Hard and soft restarts (of both the program and the computer) haven't prevented the issue either. I'll keep trying different combinations of things and report back with success/failure. Thank you for the input so far.